# Html5 drag/drop prevent element from flying back

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drag-and-drop, drag

I am working on implementing Html5 drag/drop and noticed that sometimes there is an effect of an element flying back to the original element after being dropped.

Has anyone else seen this, trying to get rid of it and not quite sure how ?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)